# How to save all raw files from a web browser?

Tags: html, web-scraping, browser, proxy

How can i save all pages sources loaded from a website, including images, js files, and any webstream to some local folder, while i am visiting them?

So i need to be able to use the browser normally, but then later be able to inspect the source files, one by one.

I used to use "Fiddler" with a special plugin, but recently, some sites do not work at all with it enabled.
My guess, probably because the fake HTTPS it adds, and that the webapps now directly verify the HTTPS ceritificate, or because of 'webstreams'.

So is there a proxy to offer similar behavior, or a way to do it from within the browser itself.

Answer (score 2):

Best I've found is [this.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-all-resources/abpdnfjocnmdomablahdcfnoggeeiedb?hl=en)

Inspect element on the website your on (F12) where you see all the tabs (i.e.; Console, Sources, Network, etc.) and click on a newly added tab `ResourcesSaver`. You can edit a few configurations to your liking, and from their simply click the `Save All Resources` button on whatever webpage you're on. It preserves the directories of all the files as well, keeping the hiearchy intact. Hopefully this will work as well as your previous one.

Comment: not sure that will work for everything, i am hoping to browse the site normally, going from one page to another, and have everything automatically saved.

Answer (score 1):

Hitting `Ctrl + S` on the website you want to save will save the current page you are on. When you later see the dir where you have saved the files you will find another folder saying (The name which you saved the file) files. Here you will find all the data form the site. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use a program [like WebSiteSniffer](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/web_site_sniffer.html) to automatically save all websites and files you visit to your computer. It can save HTML, CSS, XML, Images, Flash, and more

[image: Image of WebSiteSniffer Interface]

Answer (score 0):

Best tool I ever had opportunity to work with is [python scrapy](https://scrapy.org).

It has the best of all scrapers, and is very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can export your history from the browser and use some external tools that can do the scraping

ie. python scrapy (with coding)
or wget with few option without coding